# how to avoid changes on video height while changing its attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

click on a button changes video `poster` and `src` attributes
after the click video height becomes `0` - a short period - but enough to produce an ugly effect on entire page
how to avoid this?
**note** - `lorem.mp4` and `ipsum.mp4` have the same resolution and dimensions

```
<video class='vtop' id='player' controls poster='lorem.jpg'>
<source src='lorem.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

**js**

```
var player = $('#player');
$('button').on('click', function(){
    player.attr('poster', 'ipsum.jpg');
    player.attr('src', 'ipsum.mp4');
    player[0].play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and add a css file to it and give the video a fix height:

```css
video {
  height: 400px;
}
```

I think it is enough and I don't see any special effect when I click button.

Comment: and video is not responsive in that case

Answer (score 0):

The height is changed because your video player height depends on the video height. And when you change `src` video player height changes as well. What you need to do, is just specify `height` for your `video` tag.

Comment: no, the new video is the same height. Also, fixed height is not responsive

Comment: You can specify min-height then. So for the moment when a video is loaded, the player will have a min-height value. if you really want the player to keep the old height, on your click handler you can measure the current height before src change, apply it, and then remove on `loadeddata` event